# python while loops in a function

Tags: python-3.x, function

Can anyone please tell me why the "While loop" in the following code is not working as I am expecting to work? I want this code to ask for two inputs and then print.

```
def make_album(artist_name, album_title):
    ''' This function uses return option'''
    album_details =  artist_name + '' +  album_title
    return album_details
    while True:
        print("\n enter artist_name")
        print("\n enter q to quit")
        artist_name = input("artist_name: ")
        if artist_name == 'q':
            break
        album_title = input("album_title: ")
        if album_title == 'q':
            break
        album_details_Raj = make_album(artist_name, album_title)
        print(album_details_Raj)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you're passing two parameters to the function, what are you using them for? Also, what is the intended purpose of the `while` loop?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to write a code that will take two arguments defined through a While Loop. Why do you think While statement should not be indented?

Comment: I think you might have mistaken intended for indented. What do you want the function to do? Do you want it to return information to where it was called or just print out the output of the `make_album()` function?  It looks like you are trying to do 2 different things with the function.

Comment: You don't need a while loop to print things. And you seem to be misunderstanding the difference between `return` and `print`

Comment: How are u calling this function? Can u post that here.

Comment: Basically, I want this code to take inputs from the user and just print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A python function works as

```
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

The function uses whatever is passed into them.

You also have the function call itself. This is only useful if you are trying to have recursion, but it does not seem like you need it.

Try having the code look like this:

```
def make_album(artist_name, album_title):
    ''' This function uses return option'''
    album_details =  artist_name + '' +  album_title
    return album_details 

while True:
    print("\nenter artist_name")
    print("\nenter q to quit")
    artist_name = input("artist_name: ")
    if artist_name == 'q':
        break
    album_title = input("album_title: ")
    if album_title == 'q':
        break
    album_details_Raj = make_album(artist_name, album_title)
    print(album_details_Raj)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `return` statement before the `while` loop. Using `return` in a function will cause the function to not continue further.

Comment: Moving return statement after While loop does not fix the problem. Any other advice?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how you intend your code to work, what is the expected functionality?

Comment: I am expecting the code to take two inputs: one for artist_name and other for album_title. Then print them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to not indent the loop. It does not need to be in the function. Otherwise, the return statement prevents the loop from starting

```
def make_album(artist_name, album_title):
    ''' This function uses return option'''
    album_details =  artist_name + ' ' +  album_title
    return album_details

while True:
    print("\n enter artist name and album title")
    print("\n enter q to quit")
    artist_name = input("artist_name: ")
    album_title = input("album_title: ")
    if artist_name == 'q' or album_title == 'q':
        break
    album_details = make_album(artist_name, album_title)
    print(album_details)
```